# Wordpress 6 theme creation

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to create a new Wordpress theme and noticed differences of markup between the documentation (at https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions) and the default WP themes (e.g. twentytwentyfour).

For example, the documentation says that listing a comment is done by calling a php function (e.g. wp_list_comments()), while the themes use HTML-style markup (e.g. <! -- wp:query -- >).

Which one is correct and where do I find the documentation for the HTML style code?
Also, is the PHP style deprecated or going to be?

I tried both styles and both work. I just don't know if the HTML style is documented and is the new way of creating Wordpress themes.